# How to get Pik running in Git/Cygwin after it gets running in Command prompt of Windows XP?

Tags: ruby, windows, windows-xp, git-bash, pik

I have Installed Ruby 1.8.7. Now I want to have Ruby 1.9.2 as well on my system.Having a windows system I have to go for PIK instead of RVm. I have already in place Cygwin and Git Bash. I now have installed pik through windows XP command prompt and changed the $PATH variable putting the pik path before ruby path. Now pik commands work sin windows but do not allow me to install  new Ruby as throws anerror "1.9.2 is unknown". My Cygwin and Git gets the ruby version right but do not recognize pik common and I am not sure how to get it done. From other article i changed the the USER PROFILE variable in one of the bash files of Cygwin and also Git and tried but to no help.

I need your help in telling me exactly which file i need to put that common and in $USERPROFILE directory i could not locate any bash file and all my installation are on C drive.